# Android App works in Debug Mode, but not in Run mode

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have gone through the similar questions asked before, but the scarce responses are not helpful.
I am using the Volley Library to populate JSON in a Recycler View.
Here is the logcat:
[Referring to other SO questions, I have found Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3ffe0e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS is not a problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGgFw.png)

Here is the Android Studio Project- https://github.com/sanke-t/Legistify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your code on github.

```
JsonArrayRequest fetch = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url1.toString(), null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject random = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Lawyer l=new Lawyer();
                                l.setName(random.getString("name"));
                                l.setAddress(random.getString("addr"));
                                l.setPhone(random.getString("phonenum"));
                                l.setField(random.getString("lawfield"));
                                List.add(l);
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                queue.add(fetch);
                r=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
                r.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
                adapter=new Adapter(getApplicationContext(),List);
                r.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Have you tried setting the adapter for your listview inside onResponse() method inside JsonArrayRequest.

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject random = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Lawyer l=new Lawyer();
                        l.setName(random.getString("name"));
                        l.setAddress(random.getString("addr"));
                        l.setPhone(random.getString("phonenum"));
                        l.setField(random.getString("lawfield"));
                        List.add(l);
                    }
                    r=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
        r.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter=new Adapter(getApplicationContext(),List);
        r.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: check the logcat first, set the adapter only when you get response, or do notifyDataseChanged() on the adapter.